# WordPress Theme TwentyThirteen php - need to not display sidebar

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using **WP TwentyThirteen**, yes a child theme.  TwentyThirteen comes with a footer area sidebar as the main sidebar and it is called after content and before the `<?php get_footer(); ?>`. There is also an optional right-hand sidebar, if you put widgets in it then it will appear.

Here's the question part: I want the sidebar with the widgets to show on pages that are posts but not show on pages that are just pages.  I'm making a combination blog/portfolio site for myself: http://marginalia.wendywainwright.com.

So the first three items on the navbar are **"blog," "ideas,"** and **"life."**  I will only be putting posts posts on those pages.

The rest of the navbar Portfolio, About, and Contact will be page pages and will not have posts but will have sub-pages.  I want to have that right-hand side bar on the post pages and have it hidden on the page pages.  I think I might have a sort of ghetto CSS way of figuring it out but I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me do it correctly/best practices.

Answer (score 0):

try adding an if statement around your right hand sidebar php code and use one of the WordPress methods

view both of these methods **[is_single()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single)** or **[is_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)**

**http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single**

```
<?php
if( is_single($post) ){
     // is post - sidebar php code goes here
}
?>
```

**http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page**

```
<?php
if( is_page($page) ){
     // is page - sidebar php code goes here
}
?>
```